# VC++ project: MSXML vs any other XML libraries

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, msxml

We are aware of MSXML, based on COM technologies. We want to use it for a VC++ project starting soon. Are there any other XML libraries do good compared to MSXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) - A C++ open source library

Answer (score 2):

Will you be using the .Net Framework if so you may want to look at using linq to xml.

Comment: Sorry, .NET is not option for us due to various project hosting setup

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/). Also, [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) is an abstraction over property trees (XML, JSON, INI, INFO at the time of writing) and relies on RapidXML for its XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

We ditched MSXML in favor of [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) for our project, although Xerces is also a big, complicated beast. The TinyXML suggestion is probably a good one if it does everything you need it to. If you only need basic SAX model support (and not a DOM), then you might also consider [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) which is one of the first widely used XML parsers.

Answer (score 1):

[LIBXML](http://xmlsoft.org/)
"Libxml2 is the XML C parser and toolkit developed for the Gnome project (but usable outside of the Gnome platform), it is free software available under the MIT License."

I have used it for many years on Win32 projects without problem. It supports both SAX and DOM style reading.

Answer (score 1):

You must take a look at Microsoft [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752838(VS.85).aspx) which is a pull parser for pure C++. The primary goals of XmlLite are ease of use, performance, and standards compliance.